# Trouble Exporting WPF ListView Data to CSV with Filehelpers

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, csv, filehelpers

Have hit a wall with this so hopefully SO can be of help and I've not overlooked an obvious question previously answered. I'm trying export data from a ListView (actually SQLite data that's populating it via a list) to a new CSV file - no fancy filepicker as yet, just need to save the file locally (it's a Metro 8.1 App but being deployed to Surface 3, not RT). I've created a method based on examples I've found but it doesn't seem to be writing the file (have searched local machine after attempting export but nothing found). It's compiling fine and I'm not hitting any exceptions when debugging, also I'm using Filehelpers 2.0 as I couldn't get the current version to install (VS 2015 Community).  'Candidate' is the class for the datasource (DB/listview).

Class:

```
using SQLite;
using FileHelpers;

namespace SolutionName.Model
{
    [Table("Candidates")]
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
    [IgnoreFirst()]
    public class Candidate
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string AreasInterest { get; set; }

    } // end class Candidate

} // end namespace
```

Method (called by a button):

```
private void WriteCSVFile(List<Candidate> dataSource)
        {

                //filehelper object
                FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Candidate));
                List<Candidate> csv = new List<Candidate>();

                //convert any datasource to csv based object
                foreach (var item in dataSource)
                {
                    Candidate temp = new Candidate();
                    temp.Title = item.Title;
                    temp.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                    temp.LastName = item.LastName;
                    temp.Email = item.Email;
                    temp.Phone = item.Phone;
                    temp.AreasInterest = item.AreasInterest;
                    csv.Add(temp);

                } // end foreach

                //give file a name and header text
                engine.HeaderText = "Title,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AreaInterest";

                //save file locally
                engine.WriteFile("export.csv", csv);

        } // end method WriteCSVFile
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: All writing and reading to the file system must be in an Async method and Awaited.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I gather Filehelpers handles async internally though and doesn't require async methods to be used (AFAIK).

Comment: Try specifying a path in `engine.WriteFile()` so you know where to look.

Comment: Not sure why you would have a problem installing the latest file helpers as you can just nuget it into the project. When you say you are using v2.0 are you actually using that version or a latest version in that series ? There were a lot of changes made during 2.0s lifetime.

Comment: Thanks netniV, I was getting an error on install with the latest stable release - Failed to add reference to ‘System.***’. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache. (Forget which System library, don't have it open, will check, along with 2.0 version).

Comment: Thanks shamp00, will see if I can specify a path.

Comment: If you can get the upgrade working, I would definitely use it but you'd need to post the errors that you are getting.  Chances are it will come down to the Framework version you are targeting.  If you have a small sample project that demonstrates the same problem, I can look at it for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Testing: Passed

- Version 3.2: No issues
- Version 2.2: No issues

Using either version of FileHelpers this works as expected.  I threw the following code into a test console and it ran through perfectly so my only suggestion now is that you are either not passing it data, or attempting to write to either a read-only or invalid location.

- Do you see any exceptions in the Output tab of Visual Studio?
- Have you confirmed you have data going into the **dataSource** parameter?
- Have you confirmed the full path that you are writing the export.csv to?
- Do you have the csv file open in Excel?

***Note:*** that having the CSV open in Excel causes a full lock on the CSV file so you must exit Excel or close the file to be able to write to it

---

### Code:

```
    static void TestMain2(string[] args)
    {
        List<Candidate> source = new List<Candidate>()
        {
            new Candidate() { Id = 1, Email = "test1@test.com", Title = "Mr", FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Flintstone", AreasInterest = "Area1", Phone = "+44 1234 123123" },
            new Candidate() { Id = 3, Email = "test2@test.com", Title = "Mr", FirstName = "Barney", LastName = "Rubble", AreasInterest = "Area2", Phone = "+44 1234 231231" },
            new Candidate() { Id = 2, Email = "test3@test.com", Title = "Mrs", FirstName = "Wilma", LastName = "Flintstone", AreasInterest = "Area3", Phone = "+44 1234 312312" }
        };
        WriteCSVFile(source);
    }

    private static void WriteCSVFile(List<Candidate> dataSource)
    {

        //filehelper object
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Candidate));
        List<Candidate> csv = new List<Candidate>();

        //convert any datasource to csv based object
        foreach (var item in dataSource)
        {
            Candidate temp = new Candidate();
            temp.Title = item.Title;
            temp.FirstName = item.FirstName;
            temp.LastName = item.LastName;
            temp.Email = item.Email;
            temp.Phone = item.Phone;
            temp.AreasInterest = item.AreasInterest;
            csv.Add(temp);

        } // end foreach

        //give file a name and header text
        engine.HeaderText = "Title,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AreaInterest";

        //save file locally
        engine.WriteFile("export.csv", csv);

    } // end method WriteCSVFile
```

---

### CSV File

> Title,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AreaInterest
>
> 0,Mr,Fred,Flintstone,test1@test.com,+44 1234 123123,Area1
>
> 0,Mr,Barney,Rubble,test2@test.com,+44 1234 231231,Area2
>
> 0,Mrs,Wilma,Flintstone,test3@test.com,+44 1234 312312,Area3

### Notes:

- The ID column wasn't copied over so this was always zero, but that may just have been because of your sample code.
- I believe it's recommended to be using the generic FileHelperEngine rather than typeof() parameter on the base class since this initialises various methods/properties to utilise T rather than just a generic object.
- You can try downloading the source to FileHelpers and linking your project directly to the library to debug what's going on internally.
- You did previously mention that you have a System.*.dll referencing problem, check that you are using the Full Framework and not a Client one as that may cause that issue.  I am not sure whether a W8 universal app allows that though.